# Telerik Grid. How to tell which button is clicked on on OnDelete() client action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

In Telerik Grid, how to tell which button is clicked on when OnDelete() client action is triggered? Or is there any pre or post action for OnDelete()?

I want to implement some custom logic which only be triggered when the user hits on OK button in the confirmation dialog.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Currently not. What you can do is bind your own click handler to the delete button during the OnRowDataBound event:

```
function onRowDataBound(e) {
    $(e.row).find(".t-grid-delete").click(function(e) {

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is triggered when the user clicks on the button. Is there anyway to bind this function with the buttons (OK, Cancel) on the confirmation dialog?

Comment: @sza : The confirmation dialog returns true (if click ok) or false (if cancel). I would suggest to suppress the default confirmation dialog that Telerik grid pops up, and instead use your own confirm() dialog. This way you are spawning the confirm from inside the click handler (in Atanas' answer) and then you can attach any other code you like in response to the user's response to your custom confirm dialog.

Comment: @David Khaykin, thanks but I am afraid that you didn't get my idea. Atanas' solution doesn't work since the click function will be triggered no matter which button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but the DeleteConfirmed is triggered after the user "confirms" the delete.  This logic handles the first "GridDelete" and the "DeleteConfirmed".

```
  [HttpPost, ActionName("GridDelete")]
  [GridAction]
  public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
  {
      lm_r_category category = db.lm_r_category.Single(l => l.cat_id == id);
      db.lm_r_category.DeleteObject(category);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return View(new GridModel(db.lm_r_category));
  }
```